# Working out expected values of coin flipping games when starting with an initial value

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose I start with $\$50$ and I flip a fair coin, where flipping heads rewards me with $\$2$ and flipping tails loses me $\$1$, and I either flip until I run out of money, or I flip 100 times otherwise. What is the expected value of this game, considering that my profits do not include the initial $\$50$?

Clearly, if I consider the more basic game of starting with $\$0$ and flip 100 times, then the expected value can be calculated to be $\$50$. Moreover, the case of running out of money yields an expected value of $0$, but I don't know how to put this all together

Comment: Surely if you run out of money, your profit is $-50$?

Comment: @jlammy no, because you do not keep the $\$50$.

Comment: Well, before the game started you had $\$50$. Now after playing the game a bit you have nothing. Sounds like $-\$50$ profit to me...

Comment: @JasonBorn You said that the expected value of the game was based on how much money you had relative to what you had at the start (\$$50$). If you lose the money, then the profit would be \$-$50$

Comment: @jlammy sorry, I think I didn't explain the game properly. The $\$50$ is a starting point once you begin playing the game. You either walk away with a minimum of $\$0$ (if you deplete the aforementioned money) or you walk away with a maximum of whatever the maximum is from the maximum number of 100 flips.

Comment: OK, so say after 100 flips say I'm at $55. What is my profit in this case?

Comment: @jlammy it would be $\$5$.

Comment: @JasonBorn ok and if I'm at $\$45$, I have to pay over $\$5$? That seems a little silly...

Comment: @jlammy No. According to the game, your profit would be zero.

Comment: @jlammy In retrospect, I see that the game does indeed seem quite silly! I didn't set it myself, however, and this is my understanding of it.

Comment: It seems clear that your profit/loss is your final total $-50$.  Thus, if you wind up with nothing, then your profit/loss is $-50$.  What else makes sense?

Comment: @lulu Okay, let's say that then...since the game clearly has a flaw.

Comment: What flaw?  I don't see any flaw.  Anyway, using the natural notion of P/L, the game  is easily simulated and that should give you a good estimate of the expectation.  It is difficult to do it in closed analytic fashion since it is path dependent.

Comment: Are you interpreting the question correctly? The question does not state most of what you are saying unless you have more on it than you have posted.

Comment: Should note:  since the probability of hitting $0$ is really rather low, it's worth solving the problem without using $0$ as a hard floor.

Answer (score 2):

(3rd edit...)

You either finish 100 rounds, or you don't. If you finish 100 rounds, you end up with an expected profit of 50\$, but if you don't, it means you have lost your initial 50\$, i.e., -50\$ profit. You lose if you flip 50 tails in a row, or 52 tails and one head, or 54 tails and 2 heads, etc. The only condition in each case is that your last three outcomes should be tails, which makes all losing scenarios disjoint. The probability of losing being:

$P_L = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{16} {47+3k \choose k} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{47+3k} \approx 1\times 10^{-10}$

So, keep playing! You will end up with +50\$.